# See 10+ means 11,12…. Right?

Tags: grammar, questions

See 10+ means 11,12…. Right? So if you say you have a 10+ relationship with your cousin is 10-11 years or 11-12 years because when I turn one year old I will have 1 years less but when my cousin turns 1 years older we will have 1 year more. Sooooo which one is correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "!I have a 10+ relationship with my cousin" doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Anton has done a good job of attempting to unravel your question. However, you need to make it clear to people who have no prior knowledge of the problem. If his answer doesn't help, please [edit] your question to make it clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could be more clearly expressed but it relates to the time you have known your cousin, not to the difference in your rounded ages. By rounded age I mean the way we say we are 10 years old even when we are ten years and several months. We round down to the next integer year.

The basic truth is that the time you have known your cousin depends **only** on when you met her and how much time has since passed. It increases by one day for every day that passes.

The correct thing to do is to round that **time of knowing her**, not to complicate things by trying to use your rounded ages. They do not increase by one day for every day that passes. As you have pointed out, they only increase by one year for every year that passes and they lead to a confused account.

{I have assumed a female cousin but of course this applies to any cousin.}